# Homotopy equivalence between finite, discrete topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

How would one go about proving that if a discrete topological space with m elements is homotopy equivalent to a discrete topological space with n elements, then m=n?

Comment: More generally, homotopy equivalences between totally disconnected spaces are homeomorphisms.

Comment: The first thing to do is show that the only self-map of a discrete space with $n$ elements which is homotopic to the identity is the identity itself.

Answer (score -1):

The zeroth homotopy group encodes the number of path-connected components, which captures all the information about the space.

Comment: So I'm in an intro topology course, I have no idea what you just said :/

Comment: Calculating the zeroth homotopy *sets* of these spaces is not any easier than solving the problem without machinery the OP obviously doesn't have.

Comment: Without those words: If you count the number of path components, you get that a discrete space with m elements has exactly m path componentsand the number of path components is invariant under homotopy equivalence.

Comment: The "machinery" is almost no machinery at all, as Henrik points out, and is basically the only reasonable way to solve the problem, up to equivalent statements.